# Get wearable actions in a notification

Tags: android, notifications, listener, android-notifications

Is it possible to get an added wearable action to a notification? I tried to use a simple app that add an action for android wear. Then I tried to use a notification listener service to read the notification. The actions field however is empty and it is filled only when a smartphone action is added. How can I do?

Comment: what you mean by `to get an added wearable action to a notification?`

Comment: An app can add an action to a notification. The action, however, can be added with addAction() or via extend(). In the last case you can add an action with a wearableExtender for example. The problem is that in this case the action is not added to the public actions array of the notification, so I don't know how to get it in order to use it.